# Do I always need to JOIN on the Users table ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am writing my first ASP.NET MVC application. I'm retrieving user data from a bunch of tables and I need to make sure I only return data related to the currently authenticated user. I find myself doing a lot of repetitive code, notably in my LINQ queries - I always have to join back onto the AspNetUser's ID field so I only get data which the current authenticated user owns. Short of each user having their own table, is there a nice way so I can just write LINQ queries without having to add conditionals like:

```
(from .... join ....
WHERE db.Users.ID == Customers.AccountOwnerID
select ...)
```

My gut tells me there must be a better way, but google turns up little.

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: IMO, If you really need the authenticated user's data, you're doing it right. Besides, relational database tables are really made to be joined. If you are really concerned on the performance, you can use miniprofiler (http://miniprofiler.com/) to see the performance of your queries.

Comment: not so much about performance, more about repeating. Likely just a personal thing, but in this day and age, it feels a little bit old school.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a wrapper class based on your needs. See the scott's comment which may answer you. (I cant link to the exact comment. search the page for keyword 'authenticated')

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to join the tables to do have such a simple condition.
When you're joining in LINQ you are basically doing

Select ...
from table1 t1
innerjoin table2 t2
on t1.UserID = t2.UserID

So why can't use just your UserID field?

You can have UserID as foreign key in your table, then you don't need to join them together.

Change your code to:

> (from ....
>
> WHERE db.UsersID == Customers.AccountOwnerID
>
> select ...)

If you don't have the foreign key, it's better to have it. You can either add it to your tables in your database, or you can add a foreign key in your "LINQ Data Object Model"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework to build your models, then there is an easier way for this. In your entity model, you can create relations between the tables in name of **Associations**. Then in your code, you can directly access the tables without making a join condition with the userID column from user table.

The end result LINQ will look something like:

```
    (from Customer.address 
    select ...)
```

where the address is an another table which is having relationship with Customers table, where **Customer** is your object holding current customer data in Customers table.

Comment: I used EF. By associations do you mean when you reference one model from another - done with the virtual qualifier in classes. I have a 1 to many mapping from Users to Customers). So I guess I can already do Customers.AccountOwnerID == Customers.User.ID, but that is still the same amount of code. I feel I may of miss understood what you said?